# AWS deployment goes down frequently

Tags: python, deployment, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So, I've got a very basic deployment on an EC2 instance that largely works, except for a couple of large issues. Right now I'm just ssh'ing into the box and running

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80
```

and I have the box on a security group that allows http requests in on Port 80.

This seems to work, but if I leave it alone for a while (1-2 hours usually) my elastic ip will start returning 404s. I really need this server to stay up for demos to third parties. Any ideas on how to make sure it stays up?

Additionally it goes down when I close the terminal that's ssh'd into my box, which is extremely non-ideal as I would like this demo to stay up even if my computer is off. That's a less urgent matter, but any advice on that would also be appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to configure your application to run as a service, with a web server. This is probably only running within your current user session.

Comment: @datasage do you have any resources to point me towards or example code on how to do that?

Comment: @datasage if I just run it as a cronjob every couple minutes will that have the same effect? Or is there a lot of setup involved here?

Comment: Cronjob is kind of hackish. You should be able to run it as an cgi service. I don't know the details of how to do this with python, my usual stack involves php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SimpleHTTPServer` just serves static pages on port 80, mainly for use during development.

For production usage (if you want to use EC2) I recommend you read up on `Apache` or `nginx`. Basically you want a web server that runs on Linux.

If you think your site will remain static files (HTML, CSS, JS) I recommend you host them on Amazon S3 instead. S3 is cheaper and way more reliable.  Take a look at this answer for instructions: [Static hosting on Amazon S3 - DNS Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312162/static-hosting-on-amazon-s3-dns-configuration/8357318#8357318)

Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

Use `screen`!
Here's a quick tutorial: http://www.nixtutor.com/linux/introduction-to-gnu-screen/

Essentially just ssh in, open a new window via screen, start the server via `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`, then detach from the window. Additionally, you should be able to close your terminal and it should stay up.

Comment: Ah woah, that's actually really cool. It doesn't quite solve my major problem here, but thanks for pointing me towards a cool new piece of tech!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this a little hackishly by putting together a cron job to run a bash script that spun up a server, but I'm not sure if this is the best way. It seems to have solved my problems in the short term though. For reference, this is the code I used:

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 80

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

httpd.serve_forever()
```

Which I wrapped in a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd relevant/directory
sudo -u ubuntu python simple_server.py
```

I sure there was a better permissioning to use, but after that I just ran

```
chmod -R 777 bash_script.sh
```

To make sure I wouldn't run into any issues on that front.

And then placed in a cronjob to run every minute (The more the merrier, right?)

```
crontab -e (Just to bring up the relevant file)
```

Added in this line:

```
*/1 * * * * path/to/bash_script.sh
```

And it seems to be working. I closed out my ssh'd terminal and everything still runs and nothing has gone down yet. I will update if something does, but I'm generally happy with this solution (not that I will be in 2 weeks once I learn more about the subject), but it seems very minimal and low level, which means I at least understand what I just did.