# How to avoid .s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ in the URL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm using static site generator `cactusformac.com` and I just hit deploy and I was hoping the url would be ONLY `beccashayne.com` but instead it is `http://beccashayne.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/`.

How do I get rid of the `.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/` and have just `beccashayne.com`? Or do I need to manually upload all of the content to an FTP thing like cyberduck?

Any advice for a super not advanced developer is helpful I have no idea what I'm doing and all of the docs in AWS are really heavy.

Comment: The link you've pasted is the S3 bucket, which is hosting the static files from your website.  You need to setup Route 53 records (or another DNS provider) and point them to your S3 bucket.  The specific instructions to need are located here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/gettingstarted/latest/swh/getting-started-configure-route53.html

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312162/static-hosting-on-amazon-s3-dns-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Use Route53 and register your domain beccashyne.com then in the Route53 then the following step:

1. DNS management click on your Hosted zones, click on your domain name
2. Click on Create Record Set
3. In the "Create Record Set" leave your Name blank; Type A - IPv4 address; Alias = Yes;  Alias Target: select your S3 Endpoint should be something like "s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com" and that's it!